# $\angle ADB=90\unicode{176}\;,\;\overline{EA}=\overline{AB}=\overline{BC}\,.\;$ Find $\angle x\unicode{176}.$

Tags: geometry

[image]

I tried to solve it with the help of circles, but I was not able to.

**My attempt:**
I tried to circumscribe the triangle $ABD$ in a circle using $AB$ as diameter and in isosceles triangle if we pass circle through any of the equal sides it bisects the base, but I was not able to proceed.

Please, help me.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or be closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognize and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Comment: Archit, you should add to your question what you tried in order to solve the exercise, otherwise your post will be closed very soon and noone will be able to help you.

Comment: I edited it Angelo plz solve it now

Comment: @ArchitTiwari, I cannot understand this part: “*and in isosceles triangle if we pass circle through any of the equal sides it bisects the base*”. Please write in a clearer way.

Comment: @ArchitTiwari, actually, your exercise has infinitely many solutions. Click the following links to see three different solutions: [link1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n1YKV.jpg), [link2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mqtyO.jpg), [link3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cH9yS.jpg). If you want that there is just one solution, you have to add other data in addition to $\angle ADB=90\unicode{176}\;,\;\overline{EA}=\overline{AB}=\overline{BC}\,.\;$

Comment: @Angelo plz tell how can we get any of the answers what are the possible methods plz help me out

Answer (score 0):

Note that $\angle BAD$ is $45°$ and that it is split in two parts, $\angle BAC$ and $\angle CAD$, in ratio $1:2$. So the red angles are $15°$ and the green $30°$.

Note the same ratio for $\angle BED$ and $\angle AED$ in this angle bisector at $E$.

Note that your $\angle x = (180° - \angle AED) =  150°$.

[image]

Comment: Piita, actually, OP’s exercise has infinitely many solutions. Click the following links to see three different solutions: [link1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n1YKV.jpg), [link2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mqtyO.jpg), [link3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cH9yS.jpg). You cannot get your result ($\angle x=150\unicode{176}$) by using only what the exercise gives, that is, $\angle ADB=90\unicode{176}\;,\;\overline{EA}=\overline{AB}=\overline{BC}\,.\;$

Comment: piita can you plz explain the solution once again

Comment: plz tell how 45